# What applications or libraries are available for screen scraping applications on Windows?

Tags: java, .net, screen-scraping, desktop-application

We develop an application that clients use side-by-side with in-house custom software. One of our clients has requested that we investigate the use of screen scraping software to provide a sort of integration layer between the two applications.

Our software is written as a Java (QT Jambi) desktop application, which hosts a web browser control, that runs the application in Javascript.

The client software is a Windows desktop thick client. Unsure what it is written in (managed .NET or unmanaged win32? Maybe even Java).

We need to get data out of our application, and input it into their application. Their application can not be modified under any circumstances. They have suggested using screen scraping to read the information from our app, and input into text fields within their app.

Are there any screen scraping applications that can be used for this purpose? Are there any libraries that use some kind of OCR tech written in .NET? I think I want to avoid the type that hook into WM_Messages, but I'm unsure why.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about making Windows API calls to interact with the GUI controls directly?  If its written in .NET, this should be rather straightforward.